# Cannot call parent fragment method from dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Apologies if this question has been answered, but I've been looking around for different things for the last two days and haven't been able to fix my code.

I am creating an `AlertDialog` with single choice (radio buttons). My dialog title, and text are dynamically created depending on which button the user clicks in from the parent `FragmentActivity`. Then, if the user clicks the positive button (in my case, save), I'd like the string that corresponds to his choice to be passed back to the parent `FragmentActivity`, to be displayed in the corresponding `TextView`.

This is my `DialogFragment` code:

```
package com.myDummyProject.FoodSelector;

import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DummyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment  {

    public interface selectChoiceDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog,String dialogSubject,CharSequence selectedChoice);
    }

    selectChoiceDialogListener clickListener;

    public static CharSequence[] radioOptions;
    public static CharSequence selectedChoice = new String();
    public static String dialogSubject = new String();
    public static String dialogTitle = new String();
    public static CharSequence defaultChoice = new String();


    public DummyDialogFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Retrieve values from bundle
        radioOptions = getArguments().getCharSequenceArray("DIALOG_radioOptions");
        dialogSubject = getArguments().getString("CHOICE_TYPE");
        dialogTitle = getArguments().getString("DIALOG_TITLE");
        defaultChoice = getArguments().getString("DEFAULT_CHOICE");
        int defaultValue = Arrays.asList(radioOptions).indexOf(defaultChoice);
        selectedChoice = defaultChoice;

        // Build the dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(dialogTitle)

           .setSingleChoiceItems(radioOptions, defaultValue, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       selectedChoice = radioOptions[which];
               }
           })

           .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_save_allcaps, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // Save selectedChoice; will be retrieved and showed in TextView of previous activity
                       // ==> THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO BE WORKING <==
                       clickListener.onDialogPositiveClick(DummyDialogFragment.this,dialogSubject,selectedChoice);
                       CustomDialogListener myParentFragment = (CustomDialogListener) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myParentFragmentTag"); // ERROR: "CustomDialogListener cannot be resolved to a type"
                       myParentFragment.refreshView();

                       // Toast informing user that choice was saved
                       CharSequence toastMessage = dialogSubject + " saved as " + selectedChoice;
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       // TODO: Return to previous activity -> make sure new values appear in the activity

                   }
               })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.action_cancel_allcaps, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                       // Toast informing user that choice was cancelled
                       CharSequence toastMessage = dialogSubject + " change was cancelled";
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }
               });

        // Create the dialog
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        clickListener = (selectChoiceDialogListener) activity;
    }

}
```

I've indicated what I believe is not working with the comment `//==> THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO BE WORKING <==`.
And this is my parent FragmentActivity code:

```
package com.myDummyProject.FoodSelector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class DummyParentFragment extends FragmentActivity implements DummyDialogFragment.selectChoiceDialogListener {

(...)

public void pickFruits (View view){

        DialogFragment pickFoodsDialog = new DummyDialogFragment();

        String dialogTitle = "Select a fruit:";
        String dialogSubject = "Fruit";
        CharSequence[] radioOptions = new CharSequence[]{"Apple","Banana","Strawberry"};
        TextView tv_fruit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_tv_fruit);
        CharSequence defaultFruit = tv_fruit.getText();

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putCharSequenceArray("DIALOG_radioOptions", radioOptions);
        extras.putString("DIALOG_TITLE", dialogTitle);
        extras.putString("DIALOG_SUBJECT", dialogSubject);
        extras.putCharSequence("DEFAULT_CHOICE", defaultFruit);
        pickFoodsDialog.setArguments(extras);

        pickFoodsDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"pickFoodsDialog");
    }

    public void selectDessert(View view){

        DialogFragment pickFoodsDialog = new DummyDialogFragment();

        String dialogTitle = "Select a dessert:";
        String dialogSubject = "Dessert";
        CharSequence[] radioOptions = new CharSequence[]{"Cheescake","Chocolate Cake","Ice Cream","Creme Brulee"};
        TextView tv_dessert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_day);
        CharSequence defaultDayOfWeek = dayOfWeek.getText();

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putCharSequenceArray("DIALOG_radioOptions", radioOptions);
        extras.putString("DIALOG_TITLE", dialogTitle);
        extras.putString("DIALOG_SUBJECT", dialogSubject);
        extras.putCharSequence("DEFAULT_CHOICE", defaultDayOfWeek);

        pickFoodsDialog.setArguments(extras);
        pickFoodsDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"pickFoodsDialog");
    }

    public void selectStarter (View view){

        DialogFragment radioButtonsDialog = new DummyDialogFragment();

        String dialogTitle = "Select a starter:";
        String dialogSubject = "Starter";
        CharSequence[] radioOptions = new CharSequence[]{"Soup of the day","Garlic Bread","Prawns with garlic sauce","Mussels in white wine"};
        TextView reminder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_reminder);
        CharSequence defaultReminder = reminder.getText();

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putCharSequenceArray("DIALOG_radioOptions", radioOptions);
        extras.putString("DIALOG_TITLE", dialogTitle);
        extras.putString("DIALOG_SUBJECT", dialogSubject);
        extras.putCharSequence("DEFAULT_CHOICE", defaultReminder);

        radioButtonsDialog.setArguments(extras);
        radioButtonsDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"pickFoodsDialog");
    }

    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String dialogSubject, CharSequence selectedChoice) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        if(dialogSubject.equals("Fruit")){
            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_tv_fruit);
        }else if (dialogSubject.equals("Dessert")){
            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_dessert);
        }else if (dialogSubject.equals("Starter")){
            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_starter);
        }
        tv.setText(selectedChoice);
    }

        public void refreshView(){

        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = new getFragmentManager(); // ERROR: "getFragmentManager cannot be resolved to a type"
        Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myParentFragmentTag"); // ERROR: "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type AddModule"
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

When I press the `SAVE` button, the toast message displays fine, and then the dialog closes, however I think that the method `onDialogPositiveClick` is not being called in the parent `FragmentActivity`, since the `TextViews` never change. I thought this would be managed by the `clickListener`.

Comment: change this `TextView tv = new TextView(this);` to    `TextView tv`

Comment: `dialogSubject == "fruit"` does not work. this is not how you compare strings in Java. 2 seconds of debugging would have told you so.

Comment: @Raghunandan: while I agree that this instanciation is useless, removing it will not solve anything.

Comment: @njzk2 right. how could i miss that comparing strings `==` vs `.equals()`

Comment: @Raghunandan: when I replace `TextView tv = new TextView(this);' with  TextView tv' I get an error message "The local variable tv may not have been initialized".

Comment: @PrincessLilly This  `if(dialogSubject == "fruit"){` should be   `if(dialogSubject.equals("fruit")){`  is what njzk2 indicated. search of `==` vs `.equals()` you will get more info. Similarly for comparing other strings use `.equals()`.

Comment: @njzk2: I have replaced all my String comparisons with 'dialogSubject.equals("fruit")' etc, but the issue persists. I'll edit my code to reflect this update, and thanks for pointing out anyway.

Comment: Also, `"Fruit" != "fruit"`

Comment: @njzk2 thanks but the code I put here is different from the one I have implemented so in my original the Strings are all the same. I'll fix the one here as well so that it doesn't create any confusion.

Comment: `but the code I put here is different` not the best thing to do if you want your issues to be identified.

Comment: @njzk2 it's a common thing to have to change your code before you paste it in a public website. I haven't changed the logic of it, just the strings really. Therefore, that typo was only showing in my code here.

Comment: @PrincessLilly : I disagree. You would not be expected to post your whole production code, of course, but a code crafted to a/ reproduce the same issue b/ be as short as possible, yet complete and precise. Your issue could (and very often does (not your issues per se, but most issues in general)) come from a simple typo such as this one. Hence the need for precision.

Comment: I totally agree with you that this typo would be relevant to identifying a potential issue, so I've updated my code here. However was I what trying to point out is that when I changed my code I kept it as close to the original one as possible. Apologies for the typo. BTW the other choices for which this typo wouldn't apply don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies... use `dialogSubject.equals("fruit")` to compare strings.

The problem why your new content isn't shown in your parent fragment is that the fragment needs a refresh.

Just add this to inside the `onClick` method (`setPositiveButton`) of your dialog

```
CustomDialogListener myParentFragment = (CustomDialogListener) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myParentFragmentTag");
myParentFragment.refreshView();
```

and add the below method in your parent Fragment:
(This will refesh your parent fragment. It will remove and add the fragment to the view - that's all. The Tag (myParentFragmentTag) is necessary to identify the according Fragment.

```
public void refreshView() {
    Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myParentFragmentTag");
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I guess your MainActivity holds your parent Fragment. 
You will find code that's like...:

```
ParentFragment myParentFragment = new ParentFragment();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_main_content_frame, myParentFragment, "myParentFragmentTag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The important part about that is to denominate the Fragment. That happens in replace() --> ""myParentFragmentTag".

I hope my answer is more understandable now :)
Let me know if you still struggle with that.

Comment: If I create a custom dialog listener, isn't that redundant to my `clickListener` ? Also, unfortunately since I'm new to do this I don't how to implement that :-(    As for string comparison, why `contains` and not `equals` ? (I've tried it anyway and it didn't work)

Comment: I don't want to abuse your patience with basic questions (you've probably realised I'm a beginner :-) ), but these were my difficulties with your proposed solution: part 1) CustomDialogListener - I suppose this is a listener I have to create as this is not resolved as a type and I can't find any literature on it? part 2) check my updated code above with the errors; part 3) I cannot find such code in my main activity, nor on the parentFragment... Where exactly do I need to add it? Thanks so much!

Comment: I've found the source for my original implementation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) and there is no mention to having to refresh the view. But maybe that is needed in my case because I'm trying to put data in a TextView?

Comment: I had a pretty similar issue and what I had to do is to refresh the view. I see you're a beginner. If you're ok with that you can upload your code somewhere and provide the link to that source. I'll have a look and get this running next week. I'll post the solution here too for other users of stackoverflow. How about that? :)

Comment: thanks very much for your generosity! I had to move away from this design for usability reasons. I will put my old code somewhere, after I clean it up a bit, but before that I need to finish this project urgently, so I'll do that as soon as I can, but not right away. Thanks once more! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to kudos your comment :-(